# How do I find the right combinators to make this code working with rayon?

Tags: rust, iterator, rayon

I'd like to change the below code to avoid using .unwrap or .expect :

```
thread::scope(|s| {
    for name in names {
        s.spawn(move |_| {
            let path_to_file = format!("{}{}", base, name.as_str());
            let path_to_file_written = format!("{}{}", guichetout, name.as_str());
            write_file(path_to_file.as_str(), name.as_str(), guichetout)
                .expect("cannot write data");
            log_hash(&path_to_file_written)
                .expect("Cannot write hash !");
        });
    }
})
.unwrap();
```

I'm currently using crossbeam_utils::thread and I'm thinking about switching to rayon. So I need to change this code into an iterator with various combinators.
I've tried a lot of things but nothing works properly. So if anyone can help me, that would be great.

Comment: `names` looks like it already is an iterator. What exactly did you try, and what roadblocks did you hit?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough I guess. Yes names is already an iterator but my problem is to find the good combinators to turn this code ready for rayon. I've tried many things with .map, .for_each() but I cannot find a way to make it work chaining all my functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the innermost code into a function, so that you can easily return `Result` and use `?` operator to handle errors.
2. Use a channel (std's `mpsc` channel or crossbeam's faster channel) to send results back. `if let Err(e) = fallible() { channel.send(e) }`. On another thread you can read from that channel and see whether you get errors, or the channel is closed without errors arriving (success).